# Set Focus on a JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, focus, jcalendar, jdatechooser

Is it possible to change the focus from a `jFormattedTextField` to a `JDateChooser`?

I've tried the following:

```
jFormattedTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            jDateChooser.requestFocus();
        }
});
```

But it doesn't work. The cursor disappears when you press Tab or Enter.

Comment: "Because the focus behavior of this method is platform-dependent, developers are strongly encouraged to use `requestFocusInWindow()` when possible."—[`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

Answer (score 1):

requestFocusInWindow() solved the issue. Thanks!

```
jFormattedTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        jDateChooser.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way

```
jDateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().requestFocusInWindow();
```